# How to mock sql queries in golang

Tags: go, mocking

is there any go package or third party repo that offers mocking of database queries in golang?

pgConnPool, err = pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), dbUrl)

res, err := pgConnPool.Exec(context.Background(), selectQuery)

how do i mock the above two statements?

Comment: You can use sqlmock for this

Comment: why do you need to mock? You can create postgres based docker image and run your tests inside it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pgx, https://github.com/pashagolub/pgxmock might do the trick for this case.